# Is it possible to push a branch to two remotes, each with different branch names?

Tags: git

I have two repositories (two remotes).

I have a branch `staging` that I would to push to remote `a` on branch `staging` and remote `b` on branch master.

So essentially:

```
staging -> a/master
staging -> b/staging
```

Is this possible to configure with git's config? So I would need a single `git push`?

As an alternative I can do:

```
git push a staging/master
git push b staging/staging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot configure 2 remotes for a branch and cannot configure [push.default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault) to push to differently named branches. You need to run these commands:

```
git push a staging:master
git push b staging:staging
```

The last one can be abbreviated as

```
git push b staging
```

You can configure the upstream remote for the branch with the command

```
git push -u b staging
```

and now bare `git push` will push `staging` to remote `b` branch `staging`, but that's all. The first command (`git push a staging:master`) cannot be shortened or automated.

Answer (score 1):

Not technically with a literal single `git push`, but you can achieve effectively the exact desired behavior with a local (project only, aka not `--global`) [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

Edit the file `.git/config` in your project directory. It's best to edit the file directly rather than running `git config ...` from  a terminal, to avoid quotation/escape issues. Add this to the bottom:

```
[alias]
  pushall = "!git push a staging:master; git push b staging"
```

(`pushall` can be whatever you want, as long as it's not a default `git` command.)

The `!` means run it from a shell (like typing it into terminal). This command says "push local staging branch to master on remote a, and push local staging branch staging on remote b, **only**.

To test, we have two remotes with a master branch and staging branch:

```
I] sean at goz in ~/d/stack (staging|✔)
> git remote -v
a       git@github.com:sh78/stack.git (fetch)
a       git@github.com:sh78/stack.git (push)
b       git@bitbucket.org:musophob/stack.git (fetch)
b       git@bitbucket.org:musophob/stack.git (push)
```

Now we make some changes and commit:

```
[I] sean at goz in ~/d/stack (staging|✔)
> touch afile
[I] sean at goz in ~/d/stack (staging|…1)
 (0) git add afile
[I] sean at goz in ~/d/stack (staging|●1)
> git commit -m "test"
[staging 64e5ee6] test
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 afile
```

Now we use our local alias:

```
[I] sean at goz in ~/d/stack (staging↑1|✔)
> git pushall
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 269 bytes | 89.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:sh78/stack.git
  bb8587b..64e5ee6  staging -> master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 269 bytes | 269.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for staging:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/musophob/stack/pull-requests/new?source=staging&t=1
remote:
To bitbucket.org:musophob/stack.git
  1e5a81a..64e5ee6  staging -> staging
```

The result is that our commit with `afile` is pushed to remote `a`'s master branch (not staging) and simultaneously pushed to remote `b`'s staging branch (not master). I confirmed this with live remotes using GitHub (™ Microsoft Corporation) and BitBucket.